# Can I get back the original column order (on a button click) when a user reorders the columns?

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

Please have a look at the following code. When I click the Revert to org order button the columns should be reordered to original datagrid order. Is there any possibility? Please help me......
//The following is my code

```
    <Window x:Class="GridTextBox.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" WindowState="Maximized" Loaded="MainWindow_Loaded" Background="Gray">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width=".25*"/>

            <ColumnDefinition Width=".25*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width=".25*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width=".25*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <DataGrid ColumnReordered="datagrid1_ColumnReordered"  GotFocus="datagrid1_GotFocus" LoadingRowDetails="datagrid1_LoadingRowDetails"  Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Background="Gray" Grid.Row="1" Height="auto" Name="datagrid1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="440" VerticalAlignment="Center" SelectionChanged="datagrid1_SelectionChanged">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Empid">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox Name="txtEmpid"   Text="{Binding Empid}"></TextBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Empname">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding Empname}"></TextBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding Empname}"></TextBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Empaddress">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding Empaddress}"></TextBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="EmpCity">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding EmpCity}"></TextBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Empstate">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding EmpState}"></TextBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="EmpCountry">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding EmpCountry}"></TextBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>           
            </DataGrid.Columns>

        </DataGrid>
        <Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Height="30" Content="Insert Employees" Click="Button_Click"></Button>
        <Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Height="30" Content="Revert to org order" Name="btn" Click="btn_Click"></Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep in memory a small dictionary  and on button click use the [DisplayIndex Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcolumn.displayindex%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) of each column to reset the original view.

---

**EDIT**: Add an example

XAML

```
<Grid>
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="281*" />
      <RowDefinition Height="30*" />
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>
   <DataGrid Name="datagrid1" ItemsSource="12345567" Loaded="datagrid1_Loaded">
      <DataGrid.Columns>
         <DataGridTextColumn Header="Col1" Binding="{Binding}" />
         <DataGridTextColumn Header="Col2" Binding="{Binding}" />
         <DataGridTextColumn Header="Col3" Binding="{Binding}" />
         <DataGridTextColumn Header="Col4" Binding="{Binding}" />
         <DataGridTextColumn Header="Col5" Binding="{Binding}" />
      </DataGrid.Columns>
   </DataGrid>
   <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="Reorder" Click="Button_Click"/>
</Grid>
```

and in your code behind:

```
private Dictionary<int, string> originalOrder;
private void datagrid1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   if (originalOrder == null) originalOrder = new Dictionary<int, string>();
   //I will save the header content as a string, 
   //but you can save anything you want to identify each column
   datagrid1.Columns.ToList().ForEach(c => originalOrder.Add(c.DisplayIndex, c.Header.ToString()));
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   originalOrder.ToList().ForEach(k =>
   {
    datagrid1.Columns.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Header.ToString() == k.Value).DisplayIndex = k.Key;
   });
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate please ....As I am new to .net and wpf I dont have a better idea on that ..Ca you help me?

Comment: I build a small example. I hope that it can help you!

Comment: Thankyou but when I am creating a dictionary as                                                          "Dictionary<int, string> orderdetails" its giving an error there as  "Expected class,delgate or enum"

Comment: Without seeing your current code it's a bit difficult to help you. Can you post it somewhere?

Comment: My reputation should be 15 it seems for voting up the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
 //This is my code behind file for the above xaml
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Controls;
    using System.Windows.Data;
    using System.Windows.Documents;
    using System.Windows.Input;
    using System.Windows.Media;
    using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
    using System.Windows.Navigation;
    using System.Windows.Shapes;

    namespace GridTextBox
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    /// 

    //private Dictionary<int, string> orde=new Dictionary<int, string>() ;
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


        }

        protected void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                Employee emp = new Employee();
                DataTable dt = emp.GetEmployees();
                datagrid1.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;

         }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw ex;
            }
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            InsertEmployees ie=new InsertEmployees();
            ie.Show();
        }

        private void datagrid1_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {


        }

        private void datagrid1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {

        }



         private void datagrid1_LoadingRowDetails(object sender, DataGridRowDetailsEventArgs e)
        {

            var txtbox = GetTemplateChild("txtEmpid") as TextBox;
            txtbox.Text = "hiiiii";

        }

         private void datagrid1_ColumnReordered(object sender, DataGridColumnEventArgs e)
         {

         }

         //declare here your dictionary
         private Dictionary<int, string> originalOrder;

         private void datagrid1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
         {
           if (originalOrder == null) originalOrder = new Dictionary<int, string>();

           datagrid1.Columns.ToList().ForEach(c => originalOrder.Add(c.DisplayIndex, c.Header.ToString()));
         }

         private void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
         {

          originalOrder.ToList().ForEach(k => 
          {            
          datagrid1.Columns.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Header.ToString() == k.Value).DisplayIndex = k.Key;
          });
         }


    }
}
```

Comment: Can you just have a look on both files and help me out

Comment: I edited your code, you miss to declare the dictionary as object outside the datagrid_Loaded method.

Comment: The name k does not exist in current context-->Do we need to declare k?

Comment: Sorry, I deleted a }. After the last ; in you code you need to add a } to correctly close the btn_Click method.

Comment: I have closed it correctly Mr.michele...But its showing the same error,Its the problem with dat variable k

Comment: Edited again: k= in the foreach loop must be k=>